# Differences between keys with and w/ ADD CONSTRAINT

Tags: sql, oracle

If i understand correctly, the only difference between

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
      id   number,
      t2_id number,
      CONSTRAINT  ExampleTablePK  PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT  ExampleTableFK  FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES t2(id))
```

,

```sql
--t1 and t2 already created
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT ExampleTablePK  PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT  ExampleTableFK  FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES t2(id))
```

and

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
      id   number PRIMARY KEY,
      t2_id number FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES t2(id))
```

is that the first and second one allow me to name the constraints however I want. The third one autofills the name with sth like `sysco00...`.

But outside from that there are **no** differences. Right?

Comment: _"the first and second one allow me to name the constraints however I want"_   FWIW, in 25 years of working with oracle AND being a big proponent of well thought out naming standards, I never felt a need to control the names of constraints.

Comment: neither do i see its worth. I just wanted to get the. I just wanted the approval that THAT is the only difference

Comment: @Rarowcun You are mistaken as that is not a difference. You can use system-generated constraint names or user-generated constraint names with **ALL** of your examples. Just delete `CONSTRAINT ExampleTablePK` and `CONSTRAINT ExampleTableFK` from your first 2 examples and you'll get system-generated constraint names. Insert those two strings into the third example and you will get user-generated constraint names.

Comment: Including the FK constraint as part of the column definition at table creation time means you don't have to repeat the datatype as it will inherit from its parent, which seems to me good practice.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson what do you mean with "repeat the datatype as it will inherit from its parent". I do understand the meaning but i never heard it in the context of databases, let alone sql. would you mind explaining what you are talking about?

Comment: As part of `create table` define the column as `t2_id constraint examplefk references t2(id)` and It will automatically pick up the datatype of the referenced column. I'm not sure why all the examples I see redundantly include a datatype, as it's just an opportunity to get it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also a *hybrid* between your 1st and 3rd code, that uses an *inline* constraint clause:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id   number    CONSTRAINT  ExampleTablePK  PRIMARY KEY,
  t2_id number   CONSTRAINT  ExampleTableFK  REFERENCES t2 (id))
```

Whichever approach you take, the final result is just the same - constraints are added to that table.

Apart from the "name" difference, note that the `ALTER TABLE` option makes more sense especially in a cross-reference situation, where two tables reference each other, e.g.

```
create table ta (ida number primary key,
                 idb number constraint fkab references b (idb));

create table tb (idb number primary key,
                 ida number constraint fkba references a (ida));
```

which just can't work because at the moment of `create table ta` table `tb` doesn't exist yet, so its foreign key constraint can't be created at all. `ALTER TABLE` comes into rescue, then.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the constraints then there is no difference between constraints that are created:

- inline with the column definition in a `CREATE TABLE` statement;
- out-of-line with the column definition in a `CREATE TABLE` statement; or
- in a separate `ALTER TABLE` statement.

In all the options above you can use either system-generated or user-generated names for the constraints (see the bottom of the answer for examples) and they will all work equivalently.

However, there can be different side-effects arising at the time when when you declare constraints in the `CREATE TABLE` statement and post-creation with an `ALTER TABLE` statement.

1. There is a time difference between table creation and constraint creation; this may be an issue if data is inserted before the constraint is created that violates the constraint and may prevent creation of constraints at a later time. If the constraints are created at the same time as the table then it will be impossible to insert data that violates the constraints.
2. If you declare the constraint in the `CREATE TABLE` statement then you can simplify the statement by omitting the column's data type and Oracle will derive it from the referenced column's data type. You cannot do that if you declare the constraint later.

---

For example:

Given the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id NUMBER(8,0)
     CONSTRAINT t2__id__pk PRIMARY KEY
);
```

You could use out-of-line constraints and omit the data type for the foreign key constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1a (
  id    number,
  t2_id,
  CONSTRAINT  t1a__id__pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT  t1a__t2_id__pk FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES t2(id)
);
```

Or, the same for an inline constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1b (
  id    number
        CONSTRAINT  t1b__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  t2_id CONSTRAINT  t1b__t2_id__fk REFERENCES t2(id)
);
```

Both tables have the same data types for the columns but to create the constraints later you would need to fully declare the data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1c (
  id    number,
  t2_id NUMBER(8,0)
);

-- INSERT INTO t1c(id, t2_id) VALUES (1, 1);
-- INSERT INTO t1c(id, t2_id) VALUES (1, -1);

ALTER TABLE t1c ADD CONSTRAINT t1c__id__pk PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE t1c
  ADD CONSTRAINT t1c__t2_id__pk FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES t2(id);
```

And, in the latter example, you could insert invalid data before creating the constraints that may cause constraint creation to fail.

---

As for your final point, you can explicitly name the constraints or use the system-generated names for constraints with all the above options by just including or omitting the `CONSTRAINT <identifier>` clause from each constraint definition.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1a_unnamed_constraints (
  id    number,
  t2_id,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES t2(id)
);

CREATE TABLE t1b_unnamed_constraints (
  id    number
        PRIMARY KEY,
  t2_id REFERENCES t2(id)
);

ALTER TABLE t1c_unnamed_constraints ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE t1c_unnamed_constraints ADD FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES t2(id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0f4c4e78d9f559a5d92791f925d9183b)*